How to transfer the bookmarks from QField to QGIS
I made some bookmarks on the QField during a field trip. Expecting the bookmarks could be transferred to QGIS via QFieldCloud. However, after pushing it on the Cloud, I cannot find any bookmarks on the QGIS. The guide for the QField mentions that the bookmarks on QField can be managed in QGIS but has no further explanation. Am I missing some key features about it?

Don't think this is possible. As the guide suggests QGIS can be used to manage bookmarks in the project - but I'm almost certain that any bookmarks added in QField are stored in the app, not the project.
